# Datastage reading Hive table via ODBC Connector

Tags: types, hive, impala, datastage

I am using IBM Datastage 11.5 and the ODBC Connector Stage.

I want to read a table in Hive (in fact, it is Impala, by Cloudera) with different data types.

I find lots of problems in data type conversions ( Decimal(p,s) to Decimal (s,p), String to WVARCHAR ...).

¿Is there a way to cast the columns so that there is no problem? ¿Is Datastage who does not comply with the ODBC standard or is Hive?

Comment: Hi carlos, your question is a bit unclear ! Can you post a sample of data conversion issue you are facing when reading from HIVE through datastage. In general you could find the max length of columns in hive and use varchar(<max column length in hive>) to read column values in a ODBC stage. As for Decimal columns you could read those with higher Presicion and Scale values and then modify the format in Transformer to do further processing in the ETL pipeline.

Comment: This may not be useful to your question, but we are using the Cloudera-supplied ODBC drivers for Impala found here: http://www.cloudera.com/downloads.html with no datatype issues.